# Use a 32-bit DSN for 64-bit MSSQL2016 server

Tags: sql-server

We recently upgraded an MSSQL 2012 server to 2016 and found that this broke existing ODBC DSNs.  It appears that the server no longer has 32-bit networking installed.

In the SQL Server Configuration Manager, the "SQL Server Network Configuration" node has a "Protocols for " which the lists Shared Memory, Named Pipes, and TCP/IP.

In "SQL Server Network Configuration (32bit)" there is no Protocols subnode.

Is it possible to install this support, or has the 2016 version dropped support for the 32-bit connections?